# Output redirection in a bash script doesn't work

Tags: bash, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have a script which ensures that the process keeps on running and the output of the process are being redirected to corresponding process_name.out files.

Mysteriously (for me atleast), the output doesn't get redirected to the file unless I close down the script though the error does.

Any clues in this regard would be really helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

until $1 >> "/root/$1.out" 2>>"/root/$1.log" ; do
    echo "Server $1 crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >> "/root/procees.log"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Aren't you suffering form buffering?

Comment: try `until unbuffer $1 ...` Good luck.

Comment: @shelter thanks, it works after installing the necessary package.

Comment: Can you put that in as an answer, shellter or w2lame?  At present this is listed as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as @shelter mentioned in one of the comments is to use

```
until unbuffer $1
```

instead